# From Puzzle to Riddle to Solution

Tags: word, optimization, english, word-ladder

Your goal is to create a **word ladder** that goes from the word "*puzzle*" to the word "*riddle*" and then to the word "*solution*". In that order!

That is, if it's possible, if not you better show me why not!

Valid word-ladder moves:

- Add a new letter
- Take away a letter
- Replace a single letter

*If more than 1 solution is found, the shortest will be accepted!*

Note: A word must be on **dictionary.com** to be counted as a valid word!

Comment: Not allowed to rearrange the letters?

Comment: Can you split into multiple words?

Comment: Does replacing all occurences of a letter count as one move?

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with the double z's

Comment: Only moves in the valid moves list are valid. If it gets too difficult I may add some.

Comment: I'll give it a while before I accept any answers just in case someone's finds a shorter one (it IS open-ended soooo)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles)

Comment: @bobble I don't think this is really an open-ended question, just a standard word-ladder question (finding a ladder of *shortest* length isn't open-ended as minima can be easily provable).

Answer (score 3):

I'm hoping we can switch between american and british english...

**puzzle**
muzzle
muzzled
muzzed
fuzzed
fuzed
fuze
fuse
ruse
rise
ride
rider
ridder
riddler
**riddle**
widdle
waddle
waddled
wadded
waded
wade
wad
rad
red
redo
redon
radon
radin
radio
ratio
ration
nation
enation
elation
velation
    *missing word*
volution
**solution**

Comment: velation -> volution requires two jumps D:

Comment: dammit! back to the drawing board..

Comment: Also, you can go directly from "elation" to "velation".  "Relation" is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

This has 14 steps from *puzzle* to *riddle*.

**puzzle**
puzzled
muzzled
[muzzed](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/muzzed)
[fuzzed](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fuzzed)
[fuzed](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fuzed)
fused
fuse
ruse
rise
ride
rider
ridder
riddler
**riddle**
*I haven't found a path that ends in solution.*
**solution**

Comment: Nice! You managed to deal with the double Zs :)

Comment: piddle paddle saddle

Comment: When beetles fight these battles in a bottle with their paddles 
and the bottle's on a poodle and the poodle's eating noodles ... they call this a muddle puddle tweetle poodle beetle noodle 
bottle paddle battle.

Answer (score 2):

A shorter path from puzzle to riddle (15 steps)

**puzzle**
muzzle
muzzled
muzzed
fuzzed
fuzed
fuze
faze
raze
rase
rise
ride
rider
ridder
riddler
**riddle**

Comment: Why the downvote, downvoter?

Comment: @IanMacDonald: That definitely could not be the case as the downvote came within 2 hours of my posting the answer, whereas your updated 14 step answer came 17 hours after my answer. At the time of the downvote, your answer had 18 steps.

Comment: @IanMacDonald: Definitely not a plausible suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

My proof of impossibility (I used a computer to reinforce my claim):

I used a very wide dictionary (235,886 words 2.4 MB)

Starting at our endpoint "solution" the only options are:

---

- solution

  - solation

    - **colation**
    - **eolation**
    - *isolation*
    - **sonation**
    - **volation**
  - volution

    - **volation**
    - evolution

      - *revolution*
      - *devolution*
    - **volition**
    - **vomition**
    - **nolition**

---

**Bold** = Not on dictionary.com

*Italicized* = True dead end

Comment: A 235886 word dictionary cant be only 2.4kbs.

Comment: Not even if it's compressed?

Comment: @Anachor Good call, why didn't windows just call it 2.4MB instead of 2,400KB -_-

Comment: @Rj because Windows, my friend.

Comment: I like that *isolation* is a dead end.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Yes it is, that's why I put it in italics.

Comment: @Rj I was making a note of how fitting it is that the word *isolation* is *isolated*. :)

Comment: Wow I can't believe I misread that, sorry xD. Isolation has plenty of siblings though, that's what really counts ;)